# Resource id #n что за ошибка?

Tags: php

я создаю файл с помощью `fopen()` например

```
$nickname = fopen("$acc_dir/nickname.dat", "w+");
fwrite($nickname, "$nickname");
fclose($nickname);
```

и когда я просматриваю файл то там написано: Resource id #6

В других файла которые создаться тем же способ разное содержимое

```
Resource id #8
Resource id #7
Resource id #6
...
```

Comment: Ошибка в написании соответствующего слова через "ы"

Answer (score 3):

Вы пытаетесь записать в файл переменную типа resourse (дескриптор открытого файла).

Посмотрите тип переменной `$nickname`, что возвращает функция `gettype()`?

```
echo gettype($nickname);
```

Вы открыли файл и присвоили переменной `$nickname` дескриптор открытого файла. Затем вы записываете его в файл при помощи `fwrite()` - это дескриптор, он приводится к строковому значению и в файл попадает строка вида "Resource id #8".

Comment: тоесть? ничего не понял. Вы емеете в виду что надо записывать в БД?

Comment: unknown type выводит

Comment: Смотрите, вы открыли файл и присвоили переменной $nickname дескриптор открытого файла. Затем вы записываете его в файл при помощи fwrite() - это дескриптор, он приводится к строковому значению и в файл попадает "Resource id #8". Напишите, что вы хотите записать?

Comment: простите моя ошыбка(( я прописал $nickname = $_POST['nickname']; а потом мой код с fopen и fwrite

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю вам подойдёт более file_put_contents.

```
file_put_contents("$acc_dir/nickname.dat",$nickname,FILE_APPEND);
```

по всей видимости вы перезаписываете переменную $nickname выше.